# In Fabric how chaincode versioning happen internally?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Scenario:

I am creating hyperledger infrastructure with two organizations each having two peers and one orderer joining two channel.

Questions:

> 1. How are we define channels at the time of chain-code installation?
> 2. How the chain-code version maintains internally?

Thanks, 
Murugesan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can install chaincode on the peer(s) prior to creating / joining any channels.  You then instantiate chaincode on specific channels.  Those channels must have been created on the ordering service(s) and the peer(s) must join those channels.  Once that has been done, you can then instantiate (active) chaincode on the channels you like.  If a peer did not have the chaincode installed at the time it was instantiated on a channel, that's ok as well ... once the chaincode has been installed, it will be launched the first time you try to invoke the chaincode on that peer.

2) When you install chaincode, you specify a version.  The same holds true for instantiating chaincode as well.